# how to display the fetched data from sqlite onto tableview in iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, json, sqlite, uitableview

i have a json data saved in my sqlite database . I have fetched the data from database in an array(moodsDataArray) which looks like this-

```
{     

data = "(\n       
{\n        c1 = 8847FF;\n        c2 =    EA8CFF;\n        c3 = D1FFB0;\n        c4 = FF63FC;\n        c5 = 6B6B6B;\n        description = mood;\n        \"font_color\" = 000000;\n        \"font_name\" = Default;\n        \"font_size\" = 3;\n        \"moods_name\" = mood1;\n    },\n        
{\n        c1 = D4FF38;\n        c2 = FFA83D;\n        c3 = FFFA9E;\n        c4 = 66FFBA;\n        c5 = 63FFE8;\n        description = \"this is mood 2\";\n        \"font_color\" = 363636;\n        \"font_name\" = Default;\n        \"font_size\" = 10;\n        \"moods_name\" = mood2;\n    },\n      
{\n        c1 = 52FFA5;\n        c2 = B8F2FF;\n        c3 = FF6EA5;\n        c4 = DFC4FF;\n        c5 = 61FFED;\n        description = \"it is mood 3\";\n        \"font_color\" = 595959;\n        \"font_name\" = Default;\n        \"font_size\" = 4;\n        \"moods_name\" = mood3;\n    },\n       
{\n        c1 = 8791FF;\n        c2 = D8FF63;\n        c3 = 3DFFDB;\n        c4 = C0FF5C;\n        c5 = FF9EE7;\n        description = \"this is mood 4\";\n        \"font_color\" = 242424;\n        \"font_name\" = Serif;\n        \"font_size\" = 4;\n        \"moods_name\" = mood4;\n    },\n    
{\n        c1 = 8AFFFD;\n        c2 = B3FFC3;\n        c3 = DB70FF;\n        c4 = AEFF9C;\n        c5 = 70FDFF;\n        description = \"this is mood 5\";\n        \"font_color\" = 2134FF;\n        \"font_name\" = Monospace;\n        \"font_size\" = 4;\n        \"moods_name\" = mood5;\n    },\n        
{\n        c1 = 6BFF69;\n        c2 = FF575F;\n        c3 = 78FDFF;\n        c4 = 61FF36;\n        c5 = 6D1FFF;\n        description = \"6th mood\";\n        \"font_color\" = 212121;\n        \"font_name\" = Serif;\n        \"font_size\" = 11;\n        \"moods_name\" = mood6;\n    },\n    
{\n        c1 = FFA72B;\n        c2 = FFD8A1;\n        c3 = FFE38F;\n        c4 = FAFFC7;\n        c5 = FFFBC9;\n        description = \"it is mood 9\";\n        \"font_color\" = C66BFF;\n        \"font_name\" = Sans;\n        \"font_size\" = 11;\n        \"moods_name\" = mood9;\n    }\n)";
    message = "moods Details!";
    status = 1;
}
```

now i have created a table view in which i have to set the title name as 'moods_name' which is a key in the above array. I tried this below method in cellForRowAtIndexPath but its not working for me.

```
cell.lblmoodstitle.text=[[_moodsDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"moods_name"];
```

please help me what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you saving JSON into a relational database?  Why not create a schema which represents the contents of the JSON, rather than storing it as one lump?

Comment: @trojanfoe -As i am new to iOS, i don't know how to represent a json schema. I will learn about it and get back to you ASAP.

Comment: @trojanfoe   can you tell me how to solve it using above method?

Comment: That problem has nothing to do with iOS or Objective-C.  The issue I have is that you are packing a structured data value (JSON) into a single column of a database and you are not utilizing the power of a relational database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above posted result is in dictionary format. There are 3 keys: data,message and status. And values of each of these keys are returned in String.So you cannot access it as an array.

Update:
For each array element, you want dictionary containing substring from `"{" to "}"`. So first replace all `"\n" by ""(empty space)".` After that `replace "\" with ""`.Now since every string content from `"{" to "}"` is separated by `"," (comma)`, Split the string using separator `","(comma)`. Now you will get Arrays of string containing contents from `"{" to "}" including both "{" and "}"` each. Now you can split it with separator `" " (single space)` so that you get array containing each element from `"c1 = 8847FF"` to `"moods_nam" = mood1`

But seriously, it gets a lot tedious to use this approach in future. Consider using other storage options such as Core Data or storing it in much more managable format in sqlite.

Comment: so what should i do to convert the values in 'data' key in an array? or string. please help me

Comment: Though the model which you are using is quite complicated, I will update my answer to give you rough idea about it